# Was the first season of Leverage shown out of order?

Tags: continuity, leverage

On *Leverage*, the first appearance of FBI agents Taggert and McSweeten in Season 1, Episode 5, *The Bank Shot Job*, where they briefly show up right at the end after everything's all over.  Two episodes later, we're properly introduced to them in *The Wedding Job*, where they meet Hardison and Parker, who are pretending to be FBI agents, and they strike up a bit of a friendship.

In Season 2, they show up again in "The Fairy Godparents Job", and mention how things have been going well for them since they last saw Hardison and Parker... including the cleanup of *The Bank Shot Job*.  Between that, and the way the ending of *The Bank Shot Job* works better if we already know who these two FBI guys are, it raises the question, was Season 1 shown out of order?  If so, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DVD order of the episodes differs markedly from the airing order, according to [TheTVDB](http://thetvdb.com/index.php?tab=season&seriesid=82339&seasonid=33295&lid=7&order=dvd):

- DVD 01/TV 01 The Nigerian Job
- DVD 02/TV 02 The Homecoming Job
- DVD 03/TV 07 The Wedding Job
- DVD 04/TV 09 The Snow Job
- DVD 05/TV 08 The Mile High Job
- DVD 06/TV 04 The Miracle Job
- DVD 07/TV 03 The Two-Horse Job
- DVD 08/TV 05 The Bank Shot Job
- DVD 09/TV 06 The Stork Job
- DVD 10/TV 11 The Juror #6 Job
- DVD 11/TV 10 The 12-Step Job
- DVD 12/TV 12 The First David Job
- DVD 13/TV 13 The Second David Job

As to why the ordering differs: Wikipedia includes [some discussion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:List_of_Leverage_episodes#Out_of_order_Episodes) on the matter (some of which appears to be very far out of date), which in turn links to a [blog post by John Rogers (co-creator)](http://kfmonkey.blogspot.com/2009/02/leverage-second-david-job.html) stating that it was a decision by the network to create a certain progression of tone among the episodes of the first season. Which sounds rather vague, but I wouldn't be surprised if there is no further information available.

That same blog post identifies the DVD order I've given above as the intended order of the episodes. As far as I know, that order avoids any obvious continuity problems.

Comment: Interesting.  The Two-Horse Job definitely feels right, tone-wise, at #3, but IMO after that nothing really jumps out as a good reason to rearrange the sequence.